# Reading text file with multi-char delimiter to a list in R

Tags: r, io

I have a text file containing text data (I mean, not tables or numbers, but actual English sentences). Every couple of sentences there is a triple asterisk (***) to separate the previous sentence from the next. I need each group as an element of a list. I've tried `readLines`, `readchar` and `strsplit`, but can't make it work.
Here's an example:

```
Hello Everyone.
My name is James.

***

Hello James!
My name is Amy.
Nice to meet you.

***

Hi Amy!
My name is Sue.
```

So I need a list of three elements, each of which is a vector containing the group. Note that there are newline characters within sentences of a group.

Comment: Do you always have the format `line1, line2, empty_line, triple_asterisk_line`? Or are the number of text lines variable?

Comment: @MauritsEvers It's variable. There may or may not be an empty line. There may be two. What matters here is to delimit the text on the triple asterisks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume `data.txt` holds your text entries. Is this what you want (in base R):

```
data <- readLines("data.txt");

#Optionally remove empty lines
data <- data[data != ""];

# Split based on triple asterisk entries
lst <- split(data, cumsum(data == "***"));

# Remove triple asterisk entries
lst <- lapply(lst, function(x) x[x != "***"])
print(lst);

$`0`
[1] "Hello Everyone."   "My name is James."

$`1`
[1] "Hello James!"    "My name is Amy."

$`2`
[1] "Hi Amy!"         "My name is Sue."
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  If your text is in a file then replace `textConnection(Lines)` with somthing like `"myfile.txt"`.

```
Lines <- "Hello Everyone.
My name is James.

***

Hello James!
My name is Amy.
Nice to meet you.

***

Hi Amy!
My name is Sue."

# L <- paste(readLines("myfile.txt"), collapse = "\n")
L <- paste(readLines(textConnection(Lines)), collapse = "\n")
v <- strsplit(L, "\n\n***\n\n", fixed = TRUE)[[1]]
```

giving the following character vector of length 3:

```
> v
[1] "Hello Everyone.\nMy name is James."              
[2] "Hello James!\nMy name is Amy.\nNice to meet you."
[3] "Hi Amy!\nMy name is Sue."
```

If instead of a character vector you want a list of character vectors of individual lines then apply `strsplit` again:

```
strsplit(v, "\n")
```

or if you just want to coerce `v` to a list:

```
as.list(v)
```

Comment: Great! The only thing is that I need each group as an element of the list. In the above example, I need a list of length 3, rather than a vector. Each element then will contain a single group of sentences.

Comment: By the way, is it natural for R to break if I print this out?

Comment: Have added an additional strsplit to break it into lines.  I am not clear what the question in the last comment means.

Comment: It has to be a list of each segment between the asterisks, not the individual lines. That is, just like v as you have printed it above, but a list instead. Each element of the list is the whole group (which maybe multiple lines), not the individual lines.

Comment: See added info at end of answer.